# React adding animated interactive background from external script

Tags: reactjs, animation, background

Hi I am stuck at adding animated background to React app which is also interactive.
I've looked through few similar problems and this page https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html but I can't find solution to my problem.
Script is written in Java and translated to JavaScript and I've bough it. There are documentation but it not mentions React. The author of the script says he doesn't know React and cannot help me.  It is working fine in normal website but I would like to adopt it to React.

The code in HTML looks like:

```
<script src="js/libs/jsband-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/anim-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="DV_ID">
   <script type="text/javascript">
     var anim = new Anim("DIV_ID", {
      //some settings
     MOUSE_IMPACT_FACTOR: 50
     ETC...
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score -1):

React is just a library to generate the view (content) of a website. You should be able to use that library you want in React, but your question needs more focus/information I think. Though I'll try my best to help.

It sounds like a requirement is loading those 2 scripts. Did you already make sure to load them into your react app, and verify via the network tools both are being loaded? If the answer to that is no, this article may be of help:

https://medium.com/better-programming/4-ways-of-adding-external-js-files-in-reactjs-823f85de3668

Once you made sure both scripts are loaded by your react app, you should ask whoever made the library you are using how it works/selects the element to inject the background. As a wild guess, I'm guessing that `DIV_ID` is the ID of the element to inject the background with. Did you already make sure that element exists at the time the code runs? You can verify this by debugging the code, and running `document.getElementById` with that ID in the console and verifying it exists. If not, this could be another reason.

The last thing that could likely be, is the element may exist, but it may not have dimensions. You could probably figure this out with the DOM inspector.